# Обновление данных в DataGrid, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть `DataGrid` в ней несколько колонок, в одной колонке находятся кнопки, которые вызывают новое окно, где выбираются нужные строки. По закрытию окна, количество выбранных строк должно отображатся в другой колонке `DataGrid`. Они отображаются, но не сразу, а после того как я сниму выделение со строки и скрою прокруткой вниз или вверх, главное чтобы она скрылась из вида, а потом покажу обратно. Данные появляются только так.
Пробовал прописать следующим образом, но это не помогает.

```
<DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" 
                                Binding="{Binding NumberOfSelectedCategory, Mode=TwoWay, 
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Кат-и" Width="50" MaxWidth="50"/>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при закрытии дочернего окна `DataGrid` сразу обновлялась, а не через прокрутку?

Comment: Мне кажется тут не нужен Mode=TwoWay, если это поле не влияет на изменение ещё чего-нибудь. Поставить mode=OneWay и реализовать у класса, реализующего данные для DataGrid интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Пожалуйста, покажите код того, на что ссылается `ItemsSource` вашей таблицы. Отредактируйте свой вопрос, добавив в него недостающую информацию.